# Disable read permission by query in postgresql for 1 Hour

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am using EDB PostgreSQL version 12.6. It is a standalone application on a Linux Centos 7 server.
I have created a shell script that drops and copy the same schema updates schema from a different server. This runs on a daily basis(And this process can not be changed).
sometimes this process gets stuck. because some users query databases at the same time.

I checked in logs and found that select queries during that time are interfering with this process and both processes are getting locked.

I want to stop all incoming queries to the database during the schema drop and copy process to avoid any lock.

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy the schema updates to new, differently named tables and when the copy is complete, quickly drop the tables and rename the new, differently named tables to their actual names.

Comment: Total tables in schema are more than 100.

Comment: Make sure that these users can't connect to the database, and kick 'em out before you start your proces. REVOKE CONNECT does magic. (or improve your proces, I don't think there is a need to block the users... )